# Symbols like @ but based on letters other than a

Tags: fonts, symbols

I'd like to use symbols like the "at symbol" @ but based on letters other than "a". Any idea how I can get this? Handmade example based on "u":

[image: Handmade llustration with something based on the letter "u"]

Comment: `@` isn't really based on `a` any more than `&` is based on `et` or `w` is based on `vv`  they are simply distinct letters with some history in real life that has no affect on their use in fonts.  are you looking for `\textcircled{x}` ?

Comment: The \textcircled thing does not give me what I want. I've modified the original question adding an example based on the letter "u".

Comment: if you said where you got that U you could probably use the same font in latex, but that is not like `@` which is a separate character that is just a u in a stylised font. Oh sorry handmade... In that case you would need to use tikz or pstricks or some such to draw most of a circle around the u

Comment: Scanning through the comprehensive LaTeX symbol list I found `\textcopyright`, `\textregistered`, `\textcircledP` and `\textcopyleft` (?).  Fontawsome is a likely source, but no `\faHandmade`.

Answer (score 4):

Just a proof of concept here. Definitely doesn't look great for all letters, but here is a possibility using Ti*k*z. Basically, the command `\atish` will draw 3/4 of a fixed-size circle around the center of the argument, and then stylize the end to mimic the @ symbol, and connect the beginning to the bottom right of the text using `(A.base east)` as a locator. Looks OK if the letter has a serif at the lower right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\atish}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.15]
    \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt](A){\footnotesize #1};
    \draw[very thin] (0:3pt)to[out=270, in=0]([shift={(-.27pt,.14pt)}]A.base east)(0:3pt)([shift={(-.27pt,.09pt)}]A.base east)to[out=0, in=270](0:3pt);
    \draw[very thin, line join=round, looseness=.7](0:3pt) arc(0:270:3pt) to[out=0, in=210] ++(2.7pt,.6pt) --++(.3pt,0) to[out=210, in=0] (270:3pt);
    \useasboundingbox(-3.45pt,-3pt)rectangle(3.45pt,3pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

@: \atish{d}\atish{f}\atish{i}\atish{u}\atish{x}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's helpful, many thanks. When I change the font size for the whole document, though, the symbols become ugly. But I kind of see how to proceed.